# Decide whether a discrete random variable is usual or unusual using Probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

We know that in frequency distribution we decide whether a value is usual or unusual depending on how many standard deviations it's away from mean.

Moving forward to Probability distribution my teacher explained that we calculate the mean using the following formula ' ∑ [x.P(x)] ', later he said that we can decide whether the discrete random variable 'x' is usual or unusual by calculating how many standard deviations is the 'x' away from 'mean.

This doesn't make sense to me since we calculated the mean by multiplying 'the value of the discrete variable' by 'the probability of that variable', so the probability is involved in this formula, as well as the standard deviation formula, shouldn't we decide whether the 'x' is usual or unusual by looking at its probability?

Comment: Consider a variable that takes on values in ${1, 2, \dots, 1000}$, each with probability $1/1000$.   Is $x = 500$ unusual?  Are there any values of $x$ that *aren't* unusual, using probability as a criterion?   If all values are unusual, does the word "unusual" have any useful meaning?

Comment: What is needed is a definition of 'unusual'. @jbowman points out that a "probability" definition doesn't work well for discrete uniform distributions. For $\mathsf{Binom}(n=64, p=1/2),$ the smallest individual values also lie $\pm 2\sigma$ away from $\mu,$ so both definitions make sense.  But there are discrete distributions in which the smallest probabilities are near the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are usually skipped in classes, for a teacher and students. Outlier is a very vague concept and there are many different ways to determine.

So, back to your question,

> shouldn't we decide whether the 'x' is usual or unusual by looking at its probability?

Yes, if you know the probability. However, we don't know the density in practice. Thus, we calculate the "sample" mean, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n x_i$, not the population mean. If we assume that the distribution is unimodal, has a heavy probability around a mean (or median) like a normal distribution, then if a value is far from the mean, we would say that is unusual.

> This doesn't make sense to me since we calculated the mean by multiplying 'the value of the discrete variable' by 'the probability of that variable', so the probability is involved in this formula, as well as the standard deviation formula

Probability never involves in the method. Only sample mean and sample standard deviation are used.

Apart from the method you are struggling with, we usually draw histograms or can use another criterion.

Comment: The example he used in probability distribution was a "weighted die" and he calculated the mean in this formula ' ∑ [x.P(x)]'
x values: 1,2,3,4,5,6
p(x): 0.05, 0.15, 0.35, 0.30, 0,10, 0.05
later on he calculated the variance using a formula that I couldn't find on the internet: ' ∑[x^2. p(x)] - mean ^ 2

Comment: @Karim Ok. So, you know all about the population and you never sampled from it. To calculate the variance, he just used a basic equation $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)$. In that case, to determine whether x=1 is unusual or not, you can directly see the probability, 0.05. Some would say yes, and some no.